# Segmentation fault in creating a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have this code that creates a linked list but I get a segmentation fault error. Any solutions?

```
    struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    char *a = title_parser(bytes, temp);
    head = temp;

    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    title_parser(a, temp);

    puts(a); // Is NULL

    struct node* temp1 = head;
    while(temp1->link != NULL)
    {
            temp1 = temp1->link;
    }
    temp1->link = temp;
```

EDIT: After the program traverses the function `title_parser`, memory is allocated for temp again but when the second time `title_parser` is called, this is when segmentation fault occurs.

This is my code for title_parser

```
char* title_parser(char *bytes, struct node *temp){

char *ptr = strstr(bytes, "<title>");


if (ptr) {

    /* Skip over the found string */
    ptr += 7;
    char *ptr2 = strstr(ptr, "</title>");
    if (ptr2) {
        char* output = malloc(ptr2 - ptr + 1);
        memcpy(output, ptr, ptr2 - ptr);

        output[ptr2 - ptr] = 0;

        if(strcmp(output,"TechCrunch")!=0 && strcmp(output,"VentureBeat")!=0){
            temp->title = output;
            temp->link = NULL;
            puts(temp->title);
            free(output);
            char *load = pubdate_parser(ptr2, temp);
            return load;
        }
        else{
            title_parser(ptr2, temp);
        }
    }
}
```

}

EDIT: Another problem is that when `title_parser` returns load, I print `a` in main and the output is NULL.

Comment: How do you know the segmentation fault is caused by the `malloc` line?

Comment: You know that you are allocating memory twice for the same pointer?

Comment: Use a debugger to find out exactly which line of code is causing the seg fault.

Comment: you need to show more code e.g. title_parser and how the 'node' looks like, it doesn't look like you initialize 'link' from the code you show and you still check if its null

Comment: What is in "bytes"? This code is really hard to read because of the `temp` being used in two places, and `temp1` as well. Also the while loop will never terminate since you're not changing `temp1->link`.

Comment: Post code that reproduces the problem; not for you, *for us*. The posted code offers no evidence that `temp`'s members are initialized. If you think whatever `title_parser` does to `temp` isn't relevant, think again. If `temp`'s `link` member isn't initialized in that function to NULL, this code invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: `free(output);` That doesn't belong in your function. You just saved a pointer to that memory: `temp->title = output;`, and I'm going to guess you don't want `temp->title` to leave this function with a dangling value.

Comment: "Another problem is that when title_parser returns load, I print a in main and the output is NULL." - `load` is synonymous with the return value of `pubdate_parser`, which once again, *we don't have*. Pretend for a moment you don't have the code needed to reproduce your problem; now stop pretending, because that is *exactly* the position *we* are in. Once more *Post code that reproduces the problem; not just for you: for us.* It is called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If we can copy/paste what you post and reproduce the problem, you did it right. Otherwise...

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion,this fault isn't caused by malloc line,you can check your function title_parser(bytes, temp)，you can note it,and run your program again.
this is my test code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    struct node{
        int val;
        struct node *next;
    };

    void main()
    {
       struct node *tmp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       tmp->val=1;
       struct node *head=tmp;
       tmp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       tmp->val=2;
       printf("%d\n",tmp->val);
    }
```

The output is 2,so segmentfault didn't appear as expected.You can have a try!

Comment: s/`void main`/`int main`/

Comment: s/`(struct node *)`//

Answer (score 0):

In

```
if(strcmp(output,"TechCrunch")!=0 && strcmp(output,"VentureBeat")!=0)
{
  temp->title = output;
  temp->link = NULL;
  puts(temp->title);
  free(output);                              // error
  char *load = pubdate_parser(ptr2, temp);
  return load;
}
```

You are freeing `output` after assigning title to point to the malloced block
this will give you problems when you later try to access the memory.

Also it is good to use more describing variable names than temp and temp1
by reusing variables and using generic names you make the code unnecessary
hard to read.

You could also use a variable where it counts like when you calculate
the length of the string to make it a little bit clearer as well as catch
any error if for some reason the string has the wrong format

so instead of

```
    char* output = malloc(ptr2 - ptr + 1);
    memcpy(output, ptr, ptr2 - ptr);

    output[ptr2 - ptr] = 0;
```

you could do

```
    int titleLength = ptr2 - ptr1;
    if ( titleLength > 0 )
    {
      output = malloc(titleLength + 1);
      strncpy(output, ptr, titleLength);
      output[titleLength] = '\0';
    }
    else { some error message }
```

It is a bit hard to see what is expected to be returned from the title_parser
function, the name of the function implies that it returns the title but it does
not seem the case.